# Result set(Sub Documents) for a mongodb query in php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I am trying to get the result set output for a query. I was able to write the query and am getting the required result using var_dump.

```
$comment = array( 
               "Name" => array( 'FirstName' => $n1, 'LastName' => $n2 ) 
                );                                                                                  
$cursor= $c_users->find( $comment );    
$result = $cursor->getNext();
echo var_dump( $result );
```

But I am failing when i want to get output for a  sub document.
    In case of a normal document the below code works:

```
echo $result['variable'];
```

But consider a case where there is a document structure given below:

```
array( 
      "Name" => array( 'FirstName' => $n1, 'LastName' => $n2 ) 
     );
```

Could anyone help me with the syntax to output the first name. I was trying with below code
but did not succeed.

```
echo $result['variable.FirstName']
```

So the question is how to access embedded document of mongodb using PHP?

Thanks and Regards,
Sai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access embedded document key (property) you need to treat embedded document like an array in PHP dot notation won't work in PHP for MongoDB so you should try:

```
echo $result['Name']['FirstName'];
```

Accessing embedded document with dot notation will work in mongoshell not in PHP driver.